# Oracle Trigger with INSERT INTO table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to create an Oracle Trigger with After Update statement. It appears that I cannot create the trigger because I get prompted with Table does not exist error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USR1.CORE_FINISHED
AFTER UPDATE OF RUNTIME_STATUS
ON USR2.runtime_btc
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( new.RUNTIME_STATUS = 'FINISHED'
AND new.id = 'cr_daily')

BEGIN
INSERT INTO USR1.test_dq_log (BTC_NO, TBL_NAM, SCR_NAM)
SELECT BTC_NO, TBL_NAM, SCR_NAM
FROM USR2.EVENT_LG -- This is where the script is throwing errors
WHERE BTC_NO = :NEW.BTC_NO;
END;
```

What is weird is that the same expression when run outside of the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO USR1.test_dq_log (BTC_NO, TBL_NAM, SCR_NAM)
    SELECT BTC_NO, TBL_NAM, SCR_NAM
    FROM USR2.EVENT_LG 
    WHERE BTC_NO = 'any number here'
```

Seems to work smoothly and it inserts rows in the table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you were granted privileges to insert into that table via **role**. Were you?

If so, it works at SQL level or anonymous PL/SQL blocks, but won't work in **named** PL/SQL procedures (e.g. stored procedures, functions, **triggers**) - you'll have to acquire that grant **directly** (not via role).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the hint! When I created the user USR1, I used the statement:

GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO USR1;

Not sure how to grant directly?

Comment: Not that grant :) User which is performing INSERT INTO USER1.TEST_DQ_LOG must be granted INSERT privilege, i.e. `grant insert on test_dq_log to lorik` (or whichever that user's name is; USER2, perhaps?)

Comment: Indeed, you are correct that is what I just did and it worked! Thank you very much!